# Converting varchar to date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a `varchar` column which has values like "`Aug 07 2017, 04:14 AM,EDT`".

I need to convert this to a date column so that its possible to take the maximum value of the `date`.

I tried this:

```
select CONVERT(datetime, @dateField, 108)  
from table
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Remove the commas and the 'EDT' and it should work. The best option, of course, is to *always* store dates in a `date(time)` datatype!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `left()` and `convert()`:

```
select convert(date, left('Aug 07 2017, 04:14 AM,EDT', 11))
```

If you want a datetime then convert the date and time separately, then:

```
select ( convert(datetime,
                 left('Aug 07 2017, 04:14 AM,EDT', 11)
                ) +
         convert(datetime,
                 convert(time,
                         substring('Aug 07 2017, 04:14 AM,EDT', 14, 8)
                        )
                )
       )
```

Note:  This is not taking the time zone into account.

Comment: I think, your second query is wrong. There is too many or too less parenthesis (in my opinion first one is not needed) and `convert(datetime, convert(time, substring('Aug 07 2017, 04:14 AM,EDT', 14, 18))` should be replaced with `convert(datetime,convert(time, substring('Aug 07 2017, 04:14 AM,EDT', 14, 8)))`, because taking substring of length 18 include also `,EDT` which causes problem.

Comment: @Rokuto . . .  Good catch.

Comment: Change `18` to `8` in `SUBSTRING` function and will be great ;]

Comment: @Rokuto . . . I think I make more mistakes when I actually test code, then when I don't.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
select CONVERT(datetime, REPLACE(LEFT(@dateField, LEN(@dateField) - 3),',','') ,108 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Better Datetime solution

```
DECLARE @dateField AS NVARCHAR(50) = 'Aug 07 2017, 04:14,EDT'
-- Get index of last comma
DECLARE @validDateField AS NVARCHAR(20) = REPLACE(LEFT(@dateField, LEN(@dateField)- CHARINDEX(',', reverse(@dateField))), ',','')
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @validDateField, 108)
```